# Parsing Up A NumPy Array based on Values

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Numpy Array that looks like this:

```
[56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260]
```

How do I find the start and stop values inside?  The output should be:

```
[56, 61, 255, 260]
```

I looked at:

1. Is Increasing Function
2. Search Sorted Function

Comment: What is a start and stop value ? What is the relation between the initial array and the desired output ? Please provide more details as this is unclear

Comment: start finding min or max and look for gaps in the sequence

Answer (score 1):

So the relationship I am looking for is anywhere where the value before or after is not -1 or +1.  I am also looking for the first value in the array and the last.  Finally, the list of numbers could be empty.  Here is the solution:

```
Index = [56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260]
Master = []

if len(Index) != 0:

    Master.append(Index[0])
    Master.append(Index[-1])

    for K in range(1,len(Index)-1):

        Back = Index[K] - Index[(K-1)]
        Forward = Index[(K+1)] - Index[K]

        if Back != 1 and Forward == 1:
            Master.append(Index[K])

        if Back == 1 and Forward != 1:
            Master.append(Index[K])

Master = np.sort(Master)
```

Comment: is it the fastest way possible ? I mean for very big arrays comparing with solutions that use numpy.diff() ?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is not the way to go, but works for me so far with 1d array:

code:

```
import numpy as np

# a = np.array([56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260])

a = np.array([12,33,56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,300,301,302,303,500])

tar = []

x = a.min()


tar.append(x)
while x < a.max(): 
    x +=1
 
    if x  in a:
          pass
          
    else: 
          if x-1 not in tar:
              tar.append(x-1)
          while x not in a:
              x += 1          
          else:
              tar.append(x)


if x not in tar:
    tar.append(x)
print(tar)
```

input:

```
[12,33,56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,300,301,302,303,500]
```

output:

```
[12,33, 56, 61, 254, 260, 300, 303, 500]
```

I suspect in your question you asked for

`[56, 61, 255, 260]` but meant `[56, 61, 254, 260]`

found another way as :

```
import numpy as np

# a = np.array([56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260])

a = np.array([4,5,12,33,56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,277,300,301,302,303,500,777,888,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014])


# a = np.array([56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,277,300,301,302,303,500,777])

zz = np.diff(a) == 1

tar  =  []

tar.append(np.min(a))



for i in range(len(zz)-1):
    i +=1
    if zz[i] == False or zz[i] != zz[i-1]:
        tar.append(a[i])
    else:
        pass
        
tar.append(np.max(a))
print(tar)
```

or again using numpy.diff() in a different way:

```
import numpy as np

# a = np.array([56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260])

# a = np.array([56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,300])

              
a = np.array([1,4,5,12,33,56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,277,300,301,302,303,500,777,888,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014])


# a = np.array([56,57,58,59,60,61,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,277,300,301,302,303,500,777,999])

zz = np.diff(a) 

tar  =  []

tar.append(np.min(a))



i = 0
while i <(len(zz)-1):
    if zz[i] != zz[i+1]:
        tar.append(a[i+1])

    i += 1

        
tar.append(np.max(a))
print(tar)
```